# Проверка номера звонящего в приложении "Защиты от спама"

Tags: android, android-sdk

Делаю SIP приложение с привязкой к номеру телефона.

Приложение способно принимать входящие звонки и видит номер звонящего человека.

На устройстве установлено "Приложение для АОН и защиты от спама" (конкретно - от Касперского), но это приложение защищает от спама только при звонке через оператора связи.

Как сделать так, чтобы моё SIP-приложение обратилось к "Приложению для защиты от спама", передало ему номер звонящего и предупредило пользователя о звонке от спамера (если звонит спамер).

Comment: Возможность установить "приложение для защиты от спама" [появилось](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#call-screening) где-то после Андроид 10. Предполагается ли в вашем вопросе, что вы разрабатываете фичу только для Андроид 10 и выше?

Comment: Именно так и предполагается. Любая версия API.